# Uknown Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, double

I am unsure as to why I am receiving this error, I have had a member of this site kindly helping me so far, but we are both unsure. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("AssistantHoursAndRates.txt"));

    double UnitRM1;
        System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 1");
            UnitRM1 = console.nextDouble ();
                System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit1 = "+UnitRM1);

                System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    double UnitRM2;
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 2");
                UnitRM2 = console.nextDouble ();
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit2 = "+UnitRM2);

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    double UnitRM3;
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 3");       
                UnitRM3 = console.nextDouble ();        
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit3 = "+UnitRM3);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    double UnitRM4;
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 4");
                UnitRM4 = console.nextDouble ();
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit4 = "+UnitRM4);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM5;            
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 5");      
                UnitRM5 = console.nextDouble ();        
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit5 = "+UnitRM5);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM6;            
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 6");              
                UnitRM6 = console.nextDouble ();       
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit6 = "+UnitRM6);

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM7;
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 7");
                UnitRM7 = console.nextDouble ();
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit7 = "+UnitRM7);

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM8;            
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 8");      
                UnitRM8 = console.nextDouble ();        
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit8 = "+UnitRM8);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM9;                
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 9");               
               UnitRM9 = console.nextDouble ();     
                   System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit9 = "+UnitRM9);




    double[] totals = new double[9];        
    int unit = 1;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        double total = 0;

        int assistants = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Assistants " + assistants);
        System.out.println("Hours  Rate");
        System.out.println("------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < assistants; i++) {
            int hours = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print(hours + "     ");
            double rate = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(rate);               
            total += (hours * rate);
        }


System.out.println("Total cost of Unit " + unit + " is " + total);
System.out.println();   
totals[unit - 1] = total;
    unit++;



        if (input.hasNextLine()) {
            input.nextLine();
            input.next();



        } 


    }


        System.out.println("Comparisons are as follows;");       

    }


}
```

Input file if needed;

```
Unit One
4
32 8
38 6
38 6
16 7

Unit Two
0

Unit Three
2
36 7
36 7

Unit Four
6
32 6.5
32 6.5
36 6.5
36 6.5
38 6.5
38 6.5

Unit Five
4
32 6.5
32 8
32 7
32 8

Unit Six
5
38 7
30 6.5
24 8
24 8
24 8

Unit Seven
0

Unit Eight
1
40 12

Unit Nine
5
24 8
24 6.5
30 6.5
24 7
32 7
```

Error given;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at Assignment3.main(Assignment3.java:108)
```

The error points to line 108;

```
input.next();
```

The final print out `System.out.println("Comparisons are as follows;");` does not print out at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking with

```
input.hasNextLine()
```

which tells you that there is at least **one** more line.
Then you read in that line and without checking if there is additional data available you call

```
input.next();
```

and get the exception. Which means that there was only one more line and then the end of the file :)